# When using yarn workspaces, how to force a package to be installed in the relative node_modules?

Tags: npm, node-modules, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I love yarn workspaces, but more often than not I find myself having to pull out a specific package because of incompatibilities with external tools.

The main issue is that I don't have their source code in the **relative node_modules**, but a few levels above (which is normal for yarn workspaces and node, in general).

For instance, [ZeppelinOS](https://zeppelinos.org) gives the following error message when "openzeppelin-eth" is not found in the relative path:

> Could not find a zos.json file for 'openzeppelin-eth'. Make sure it is provided by the npm package.

Is there a way to force-copy a package? I read about [--focus](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-focus), but it's not what I need.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you're looking for is called `nohoist`
https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/

Basically you have two options:

1. do it from the child package

```
"workspaces": {
  "nohoist": ["react-native", "react-native/**"]
}
```

2. do it from the root level

```
"workspaces": {
  "packages": ["packages/*"],
  "nohoist": ["**/react-native", "**/react-native/**"]
}
```

If you want to share package `xyz` among all your sub-projects, then set it in the root, otherwise in the child project.