# When using npm workspaces, how to force a package to be installed in the relative node_modules?

Tags: npm, node-modules, monorepo, npm-workspaces

Here are some related questions:

[When using yarn workspaces, how to force a package to be installed in the relative node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910467/when-using-yarn-workspaces-how-to-force-a-package-to-be-installed-in-the-relati)

[NPM 7 Workspaces - Multiple node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68382337/npm-7-workspaces-multiple-node-modules)

[Should I have to use no-hoist for all packages in a monorepo with react-native-web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807614/should-i-have-to-use-no-hoist-for-all-packages-in-a-monorepo-with-react-native-w)

I'm using npm workspaces to organise multiple packages. The issue is that my main package don't have its dependency's(which is also one of the workspaces) source code in local node_modules. I know the dependency is installed in root node_modules, the thing is that I need to visit it by relative path from the main package.

Here is the project structure after running `npm install` in root dir:

```
root
├── package.json ->  { "workspaces": ["packages/*"] }
├── node_modules
│   ├── dependency-A
│   ├── dependency-B
└── packages
    ├── main-package
    ├── dependency-A
    └── dependency-B
```

package.json in root dir:

```json
{
  "workspaces":  [
      "packages/main-package",
      "packages/dependency-A",
      "packages/dependency-B"
    ]
}
```

package.json in "packages/main-package":

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dependency-A": "0.1.0",
    "dependency-B": "0.1.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js in "packages/main-package":

```js
{
  plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: "node_modules/dependency-A/media",
            to: "static/dependency-A-media",
          },
        ],
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
           {
             context: "node_modules/dependency-B/dist",
             from: "research-data.json",
           },
         ],
      }),
  ]
}
```

When I run webapck in main-package, the error message is:

```bash
ERROR in unable to locate '/Users/trumangao/myApp/packages/main-package/node_modules/dependency-A/media' glob
ERROR in unable to locate '/Users/trumangao/myApp/packages/main-package/node_modules/dependency-B/dist/research-data.json' glob
```

I'm wondering what is the best practice to resolve such question? The option "nohoist" of Yarn inspired me but I can't find it in npm. I also tried to run install in package dir but it will break their symlink. How could I install dependencies of each package in their local node_modules while maintain their links like lerna@4?

Tried versions:
node.js@16.13.0
npm@8.1.0
&
node.js@18.14.0
npm@9.3.1

Hope I've made myself plain with my poor English LoL, thanks a lot.